# synchronous sqlite transactions node

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I installed sqlite3 with npm

```
npm install sqlite3 --save
```

I have written some basic functions that I would like to be performed synchronously rather then with async.

for instance I would like to get column names in one function and the row count in another.

I would like to simply return these values. currently I am using a callback like so

```
d.cinfo = function(table, callback){
    var o = {};
    db.each("PRAGMA table_info(" + table + ")", function(err, col){
        o[col.name] = col.type;
    }, function(){
        if(typeof callback == 'function') callback(o);
    });
}
```

d is an object which is later exposed
however Id like to return the values

```
d.cinfo = function(table, callback){
    var o = {};
    db.each("PRAGMA table_info(" + table + ")", function(err, col){
        o[col.name] = col.type;
    }, function(){
        return o;
    });
}
```

is there a way I can achieve this. I found documentation saying it was possible but then I learned that it was outdated and im not sure its meant for the same api

I have implemented bluebird however Promise.promisifyAll(middleware) returns and error "Object # has no method .then() anyone know what im doing wrong

Comment: You can use [better-sqlite3](https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come across a problem like this and many others while using Express and it really drives me crazy where I just can't avoid callback hells.

Some of the possible solutions can be:

1. Using the same old event driven style. Instead of calling nested functions, emit events for them. But I'm assuming you wouldn't like that very much, but that atleast gets rid of the nested callbacks.
2. There's a npm module called [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bluebird) that allows you to extend existing modules with promises. (Using `promisifyAll`). So promises will still trim down the code and you'll have much cleaner code than you had before using promises.
3. If you don't mind switching frameworks, you can try [KoaJS](https://github.com/koajs/koa) that allows you to yield(fun stuff from ECS 6) functions using generator functions(another cool feature). You can have more reading about this [here](https://carldanley.com/ecmascript-6-generators/).

So the above code can be re-written like:

```
var rows = yield db.each() //or something like that
```

this is an amazing feature but the drawback is that you have to use unstable versions of    node (0.11.x). We also faced some issues setting up https using 0.11.x and had to downgrade    to 0.10.x (we're not using koa either)

If there are only a few places where you need to do such kind of stuff, I would recommend using bluebird, but if you're tired of having lots of callbacks in your code, better go for Koa, although I've already mentioned you the tradeoffs.

Comment: using bluebird can I nest a promise() in the function rather then promisify all. (I'd like to keep my inserts and deletes asynchronous)

Comment: yes you can. I just gave a short description on how you can approach to solve the problem. Bluebird is designed mainly for the purpose of converting callbacks to promises.

Comment: so I tried to use promisifyAll(require('sqlite3')) and promisifyAll(new sqlite3.Database(file)) and neither work

Comment: try having a read on this https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification
also remember that you need to call function with Async suffix once you require them using promisies

Comment: that was my problem I didnt add the Asyc suffix... lol this might be stupid is there a way to get the value out of promise(this is still worlds easier then callbacks just curious if i can make it easier) this returns a promise but drives my point var i = fnAsync().then() is there a way to return a value maybe using resolve or something... I dont think i understand resolves point

Comment: I'm not sure about that since I never tried it. But that would involve you to have access to the promise resolved inside the function(which would ofcourse be a private variable) so I think that wouldn't be possible using that. If you still want that, I would recommend creating your own custom solution using promise (like q). But that wouldn't be easy i suppose.

Comment: I'm up for the challenge because I love the synchronous db handling in php but also love being able to go async in node if I can pick and choose when I get what that would be amazing lol