# node-sqlite3 with iojs, koa and yield

Tags: node.js, sqlite, koa

I'm new to iojs and am trying to write a small web application with koa and node-sqlite3.

One thing I couldn't quite get my head around is how to use the 'yield' syntax on the node-sqlite3 callback based API.

I've googled around and all I've found was this stackoverflow post ([synchronous sqlite transactions node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702037/synchronous-sqlite-transactions-node)), which says this is possible.

Can anyone please give me a pointer to more concrete examples?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

After some more digging, I found some hint from the stackoverflow post [Koa.js request with promises is hanging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614882/koa-js-request-with-promises-is-hanging).

The trick is to use the native Promises.

Sample code below works with iojs v1.6.4 and Koa 0.19.0

```
var koa = require('koa');
var app = koa();

var route = require('koa-route');

var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');

function *query() {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var result = [];

    db.serialize(function() {
      db.run("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lorem");
      db.run("CREATE TABLE lorem (info TEXT)");

      var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?)");

      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          stmt.run("Ipsum " + i);
      }

      stmt.finalize();

      db.all("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM lorem", function(err, rows) {
        resolve(rows);
      });
    });
  });

  return promise;
}

function *handler() {
  this.body = yield query();
  this.status = 200;
}

app.use(route.get('/list', handler));

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: This is also working for me with NodeJS v0.12.0 and the --harmony flag.

Answer (score 2):

there is a nodejs module called co-sqlite3 here  :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/co-sqlite3

promise based node-sqlite3 named co-sqlite3 for co or koa

**Installing**

```
npm install co-sqlite3
```

**Usage**

1. work with co

   ```
   var co = require('co');
   var sqlite3 = require('co-sqlite3');

   co(function*() {

   //connect a database

   var db = yield sqlite3('test.db');

   // create a table 
   yield db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testtable (id INT NOT NULL)');

   var stmt = yield db.prepare('INSERT INTO testtable(id) VALUES( ? )');

   for(var i =0 ; i < 100 ; i++){
       yield stmt.run(i);
   }

   stmt.finalize();

   var row = yield db.get('SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE id < ? ORDER BY ID DESC ' ,[50]); 
   console.log(row); // {id: 49}

   var rows = yield db.all('SELECT * FROM testtable');
   console.log(rows.length);


    }).catch(function(err) {

   console.log(err.stack);

   });
   ```
2. work with koa

   ```
   var koa = require('koa');
   var sqlite3 = require('co-sqlite3');

   var app = koa();

   app.use(function*(next){
       this.db = yield sqlite3('test.db');
       yield next ;
   });


   app.use(function* (){
       this.body = yield this.db.get('SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE id < ? ORDER BY ID DESC ' ,[50]);
   })

   app.listen(3000);
   ```
3. just as a promise

   ```
   var sqlite3 = require('co-sqlite3');


   sqlite3('test.db').then(function(db){
       db.get('SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE id < ? ORDER BY ID DESC ' ,[50])
         .then(function(row){
         console.log(row);
       });
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

While promises work, the major advantage of using koa is to leverage generators (the `yield` keyword). For that to happen, the library you're using needs to be prepared to work with generators.

I know you've specified you're using sqlite, but for an example of database access with `yield`, see how this mongodb  package [co-monk](https://github.com/tj/co-monk) works:

```
yield users.insert({ name: 'Tobi', species: 'ferret' });

var res = yield users.findOne({ name: 'Tobi' });
res.name.should.equal('Tobi');
```

While you could use the [co package](https://github.com/tj/co) for wrapping node-sqlite3 yourself, if you're starting you'll probably find it easier to use one of those existing `co`-based libraries.

There seems to be a generator-ready package for [MySQL](https://github.com/sidorares/mysql-co) too, though I couldn't find any equivalent for sqlite.

In case that helps, here's a more complete blog post with examples of using co-monk: http://www.marcusoft.net/2014/04/koaExamples.html